# Limit of the sequence $1+\frac{\cos n}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}1+\frac{\cos n}{n!}$$
How would I find the limit of this using the squeeze theorem?

I have that:
\begin{align*}-1\le{ }&\cos {n} \le 1\\
0\le { }&1+\cos {n}\le 2\\
\frac{0}{n!}\le { }& \frac{1+\cos {n}}{n!} \le \frac{2}{n!}
\end{align*}

but $\frac{1+\cos {n}}{n!} \neq 1+ \frac{\cos {n}}{n!}$

How do I go around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We simply have
$$-\frac1{n!}\le\frac{\cos n}{n!}\le\frac1{n!}$$
$$1-\frac1{n!}\le1+\frac{\cos n}{n!}\le1+\frac1{n!}$$
and both the outer functions have a limit of 1 as $n\to\infty$, so by the squeeze theorem the limit of the original function is 1.

Comment: Ah thank you so much!  I don't know why I didn't think of adding the 1's after!

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the transformations in the order that they will produce they desired result. So, first divide with $n!$ and then add $1$:
\begin{align*} 
-1&\le \cos{n}\le 1  &\mid :n! \\[0.2cm] -\frac{1}{n!}&\le \frac{\cos{n}}{n!}\le \frac1{n!} &\mid +1\\[0.2cm]
1-\frac{1}{n!}&\le 1+\frac{\cos{n}}{n!}\le 1+\frac1{n!}
\end{align*}